# optimizing dask Series filtering - lazy version of Series.isin()

Tags: dask

I currently have the following pattern embedded inside a larger computation

```
seq1.isin(seq2[seq3].unique().compute().values)
```

where `seq3` is a boolean Series.
The performance seems acceptable, but it is ugly and the use of `compute()` forces evaluation, possibly removing opportunities for parallelism.
Simply saying

seq1.isin(seq2[seq3].unique())

does not work and the documentation says that the argument to `isin` must be an (I presume Numpy) array.

Is there a bettern way to write the above code?
What if `seq1` and `seq2` are the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible do an incremental set membership operation. To get a correct result, you'd need to have a fully realized set to answer the question of whether an item is a member of it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this operation using an inner join.